# Which div to programmatically click to close bootstrap modal

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I am writing tests for my Bootstrap 3.x webapp using Nightwatch. All is working fine, but I would like to add the "close modal by clicking somewhere next to it" in one of my tests. I don't seem to be able to identify the html element that's supposed to receive the click event however.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background is a div with class `.modal-backdrop`. According to the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage): "...generates a `.modal-backdrop` to provide a click area for dismissing shown modals when clicking outside the modal."

Comment: It seems it's a Nightwatch problem. 
document.querySelector('div.modal-backdrop').click() works in my browser Javascript console. However executing the 'click' command on the same selector in Nightwatch isn't working.

Comment: Anyway, I'll accept your answer as technically you are correct. This is the correct element to send the click to. The reason I asked what because none of the divs reacted to my click call, but it seems to be a bug in the testing framework.

Comment: Aand, it's not a bug. The click seems to happen at the center of the screen, thereby targeting an element on top of the background div.